# Getting an error when I call pIBidiSpl2::SendRecvXMLString

Tags: c++, printing, windows-8

I am trying to use the `IBidispl2->SendRecvXML` function and I keep getting an unhandled exception error.

I am the first to admit I am extremely weak in C++ but I know how to read and have tried to find examples or better explanations to IBiDiSpl2 functions and have come to a dead end.

I get this error when I try to debug this

> Unhandled exception at 0x69D82C10 (bidispl.dll) in V4BiDiTest.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCD0.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BiDiSpl.h"
#include "comutil.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // verify atleast 3 args ( prog.exe <printername> query1....)
    if(argc < 3)
    {
         cout << "ERROR: invalid usage, not enough arguments"<< endl << 
            "USAGE: V4BiDiTest.exe <printername> \"query1\" [\"query2\"] ... "     << endl <<
            "Please rerun the application";
         return 1;
    }

    // set the first arg after the exe to the printer name 
    string printer = argv[1];
    std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(printer.begin(), printer.end()); 
    LPCWSTR pPrinter = stemp.c_str();

    HRESULT hr;
    DWORD dwAccess;
    IBidiSpl2 *pIBidiSpl2 = NULL;
    dwAccess = BIDI_ACCESS_USER;

    // build the request schema with all other args after argv[1] 
    char* getSch = "<bidi:Get     xmlns:bidi=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2005/03/printing/bidi\">";
    _bstr_t bstrt(getSch);

    for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
    {
        bstrt+="<Query schema=\'";
        char *argStr =argv[i];
        bstrt+=argStr;
        bstrt+="\'/>";
    } 
    bstrt+="</bidi:Get>";

    hr = CoInitializeEx (NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED) ;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_BidiSpl,
            NULL, 
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            IID_IBidiSpl, 
            (void**)&pIBidiSpl2) ;

    if (pIBidiSpl2 == NULL)
    { 
        cerr << "CoCreateInstance failed" << endl; 
        return 1; 
    }


    hr = pIBidiSpl2->BindDevice(pPrinter,dwAccess);
    //Test hr here
    if (hr!=0){ cout << "failed on bind" <<endl; return 1;}

    BSTR responce;
    BSTR test1 = ::SysAllocString(L"<bidi:Get xmlns:bidi=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2005/03/printing/bidi\"><Query schema='\\Printer'/></bidi:Get>");

    // I get the error when the following line executes
    hr = pIBidiSpl2->SendRecvXMLString(test1, &responce);
    //Test hr here
    if (hr!=0){cout << "failed on send" <<endl;return 1;}
    cout << responce << endl;
    ::SysFreeString(test1);
    ::SysFreeString(responce);

    hr = pIBidiSpl2->UnbindDevice();
    // test hr here
    if (hr!=0){cout << "failed on unbind" <<endl;return 1;}
    cout << "Successfully unbound device" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you mark the line where you're getting the error. Also you're not checking the `pIBidiSpl2` for validity (being `!= NULL`) before using it. I'd suspect this is the most likely reason for getting such exception.

Comment: I added where I get the error to the code above I also added in an quick if statement to make sure pIBiDiSpl2 was not null and still get the error. Thanks for the help I was hoping :)

Comment: I guess you mean the stmt after your quick check fails: `pIBidiSpl2->SendRecvXMLString(test1, &responce);`. Sorry on the 1st look everything reads just fine (according parameter specification of `SendRecvXMLString`). Seems like an error occuring inside the `bidispl.dll` module, may be due to unexpected or invalid input from the `Test1` variable. Did you check the XML you're passing against the mentioned schema?

Comment: Yes it was on the line     hr = pIBidiSpl2->SendRecvXMLString(test1, &responce); I followed the example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183368(v=vs.85).aspx So I guess it is ok '\Printer' is the basic one and should return everything. but I will look more into that part and see if I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Could be also a bug or incompatibility issue in the `bidispl.dll` module you're using from your actual environment.

Comment: I didnt think of that, I am on Win8 Ent x64 using VS 2012 Ult if that helps?

Comment: Try to narrow that question with appropriate additional tags, from a C++ point of view everything looks fine IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_BidiSpl,
        NULL, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        **IID_IBidiSpl,**
        (void**)&pIBidiSpl2) ;
```

to

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_BidiSpl,
        NULL, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        **IID_IBidiSpl2,** 
        (void**)&pIBidiSpl2) ;
```